# Как создать хлебные крошки, оформленные в микроформат breadcrumb?

Tags: html, schema.org, breadcrumbs

Есть хл.крошки в таком виде:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <div itemprop="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumbs_inner">
        <a href="https://site.com">Главная</a>
        <span class="delimiter">/</span>
        <span class="current">О компании</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

подскажите, как правильно их оформить в микроформат breadcrumb ?
обязательно ли нужно каждый пункт оборачивать в тег `li`?
т.е. пункт `Главная` и `О компании` должны должны быть в `li`?
а эти атрибуты обязательны:  `itemprop="position" content="1"` ?

пример из `schema.org`

```
<ol itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
        itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses">
            <span itemprop="name">Dresses</span></a>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
        itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses/real">
            <span itemprop="name">Real Dresses</span></a>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
    </li>
</ol>
```

==========================================================================
**P.S.**
тестирую такой код по ссылке https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

```
<ul itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" class="breadcrumbs_inner">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a itemprop="item" href="https://site.com"><span itemprop="name">Главная</span></a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <span itemprop="name" class="current">Новости</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

но выдаёт ошибку:

```
BreadcrumbList 4 ОШИБКИ НЕТ ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЙ
@type    BreadcrumbList
itemListElement
@type    ListItem
name     Главная
item     Необходимо указать значение для поля item.
position Необходимо указать значение для поля position.

itemListElement
@type    ListItem
name     Новости
item     Необходимо указать значение для поля item.
position Необходимо указать значение для поля position.
```

подскажите, как правильно сделать разметку?

Comment: Для чего делается в данном случае разметка? Если для ранжирования в поисковиках то по логике они могут назначать "вес" по параметрам  itemprop="position" content="1" и если использовать этот метатег то его надо оборчаивать вместе с тегом <a> другим тегом чтобы была ясна принадлежность именно к этой ссылке.

Comment: Я бы написал вторым вариантом, вроде точно так рекомендует гугл https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb

Comment: подскажите, почему выдаёт ошибку `Необходимо указать значение для item.` в вышеприведённом коде? атрибут `item` есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BreadcrumbList элемент должен иметь ссылку, валидный код такой:

```
<ul itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" class="breadcrumbs_inner">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a itemprop="item" href="https://site.com"><span itemprop="name">Главная</span></a>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a itemprop="item" href="https://site.com/dresses/real"><span itemprop="name" class="current">Новости</span></a>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

либо если последний элемент нужно сделать без ссылки то он должен быть не BreadcrumbList элементом.

```
<ul itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" class="breadcrumbs_inner">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a itemprop="item" href="https://site.com"><span itemprop="name">Главная</span></a>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="current">Новости</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

это как минимум в интерпретации Гугла и его валидатора.

Я бы сделал по первому варианту, но стилями CSS скрыл бы что последний элемент является ссылкой.